# Significato di "ondoso" in questo brano

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Ogni tanto nostro padre si chiudeva con lui nello studio per ore (erano le più lunghe soste che il Cavalier Avvocato vi faceva), e dopo poco dalla porta chiusa giungeva la voce adirata del Barone, gli accenti **ondosi** d'un diverbio, ma la voce del Cavaliere non s'avvertiva quasi.

Ho cercato il termine "ondoso" in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che si usa per qualcosa che abbia a che vedere con le onde, ma non capisco il senso di questo aggettivo nel contesto del passaggio sopra  citato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'aggettivo *ondosi*, in questo brano, è un bell'esempio della scrittura di Calvino che, talvolta, invece di lunghe descrizioni usa delle parole per dare un'immagine di ciò che sta accadendo. Come si dice nella domanda, *ondoso* ha a che fare con le onde; in particolare, qui, nel senso del loro movimento e del rumore che producono. Se siamo in riva al mare, il suono delle onde non è sempre uguale, ma si alza e si abbassa di volume, seguendo il loro movimento. Così possiamo immaginare il suono delle voci ascoltate da dietro una porta chiusa, quando due persone (come nel caso del brano citato) o più stanno discutendo. Le voci si alzano e si abbassano, sono forti o flebili come le onde del mare.